# How do you denote queue, initialization, and array in topological sort?

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, topological-sort

I am making an attempt to write an algorithm for topological sort using pseudocode, but how would you denote in pseudocode the initialization of queue (Q) with 0 in degrees at start and an array that holds all the numbers of in degrees for all vertices?

Comment: You do it however you want ad long as people understand what you mean. There is no compiler to yell at you. That's why it's called pseudocode. If it had a fixed set of rules, it would be a programming language.

Answer (score 1):

As already commented: in pseudocode everything is fine, as long as you get the message across. What I typically do is have some definitions before the code block, such that the pseudocode stays clean. For your example, I would do the following:

> Given an array of vertices `V = [v_i for 0 <= i < |V|]`.
>
> Let `A(v)` be the angle in degrees between the vector `v` and the positive `x-axis` (this is an assumption; I cannot get a clear definition from your question, but this is just an example anyway).

Now, consider the following algorithm:

```
#initialize a queue Q with 0 degrees
Queue Q
Q.push(0)

#create an array of angles to vertices
A = [A(v_i) for 0 <= i < |V|]
```